# Implementation of the Mediator pattern in Mac/iOS apps (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, macos, mediator

Is there any Mac/iOS library similar to the MVVM Light Messenger, that allows to exchange messages between objects (preferable written in swift)?

I'm using this Mediator pattern in a lot of my WPF apps - it is very helpful for me, because it decreases coupling between my ViewModels (and other app components). But recently I started to learn development of native Mac apps and I can't find any implementation of described pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess **NSNotificationCenter** is what you need.

> A notification encapsulates information about an event, such as a window gaining focus or a network connection closing. Objects that need to know about an event (for example, a file that needs to know when its window is about to be closed) register with the notification center that it wants to be notified when that event happens. When the event does happen, a notification is posted to the notification center, which immediately broadcasts the notification to all registered objects.

You can find full description of this concept at [Apple Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html). Though it’s using Objective-C for examples, you can find Swift **NSNotificationCenter** class reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/NotificationCenters.html).